# Inconsistent flairs of different themes?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, mobile-web, flair

Please see the following image, where you can find the inconsistency of SO reputation score among different flair themes (one with 7165, while all other three 7265).

I always thought that these four themes are based on the same data until now. Is this a bug? Are different flair themes really updated individually?

[image]

P.S.: The inconsistency only shows on my mobile, no problem from my desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those flair images are heavily cached. The only explanation is that at some point you loaded the "clean" themed flair image when you had 7,165 reputation and it is cached at that value. Then, when you loaded the other three, it showed the more recent value 7,265 which was the value at the time those three were generated.

They do use the same data, but depending on when you load each one will determine the time from which each one represents. So it is certainly possible that they'd have different values. You'll have to wait for the server to re-generate the image to see the updated value.

This is what my flair images look like:

[image: Flair Images]

It only takes *one* user to view your flair image, *anywhere* on the web where it might be linked, for it to get cached for a while on the server.

Comment: Note that animuson's are also exhibiting the behavior; the default flair shows 72656 while the others show 72749.

Comment: @DennisMeng And pretty much any moderator will exhibit the problem because our default flair images get linked in quite a few places around the site, so it's much more likely that we'll already have an old cached copy of that one.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian *I care*! ;P I honestly didn't even think about showing SO, but that one currently has a reverse. My default shows 19,999 and the other three show 19,995 (because I downvoted four answers).

Comment: I never regard it related to sever cache stuff before. Make sence now. :P